# Toast doesn't work on real device after adding permissions

Tags: android, android-toast

I'm dealing with a strange bug on android:
I want to print something with Toast and it works great on the emulator, and also on device.
But after I add this line on the Manifest file (I must because I want to read contacts):

```
"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>"
```

all the toasts don't work on real devices (but still work on the emulator).

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonFont= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "tamir.ttf");

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    addSingleClickListener();
}
```

I don't have any idea how to solve it. Please help...

Comment: I have two possibilities for you: 1) The toast is called at a location that the phone doesn't reach, maybe as a result of you placing it where you check if you have the permission first (23+ requires runtime asking of permissions) 2) The toast is never called because of a crash, exception or something else that prevents it from being reached. Please add code, or this is guessing

Comment: There is no reason to add code, since I added toasts everywhere in the app that to make sure that i'm not wrong. I added toast in the onCreate of the first Main class. on emulator it works, on device - not.

Comment: shalom, is there anything in the log of the device? maybe exception ?

Comment: I didn't connect the device to computer yet, only sent the apk through email.  I thought someone will give me a good reason why the permission cause this not to work.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? How?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, on my real device the app crashed on some Toast, while some worked. In the emulator all Toasts worked.

I created the Toast opbect with

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

the solution was to remove the following lines for a bigger Toast:

```
if(big) {
  LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) t.getView();
  TextView mtv = (TextView) l.getChildAt(0);
  mtv.setTextSize(18);
}
```