# Toast.makeText is not showing in Android 11 (with SDK 30 emulator)

Tags: android, android-toast

According to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#toasts, Toasts should still work as normal for Android11  (only setView() was deprecated).

> Note that text toasts are still allowed; these are toasts created using Toast.makeText() that don't call setView().

However, I cannot get Toast to show for emulators running SDK30 with

```
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3" 
    and with targetSdkVersion 30
```

The code used was just a simple

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HELLO WORLD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The toast is displayed when I change the targetSdk to 29 (or with devices <SDK30).

**Do I need to add any <queries> tags in manifest file for Toasts ?
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility**

I've also tried the following without luck.

1. rebooting the emulator [Toast not showing in Android Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56017928/toast-not-showing-in-android-q)
2. notification ON [Toast message not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601611/toast-message-not-shown/29785345#29785345)

Comment: Confirmed. Configuration to reproduce: `compileSdkVersion 30` and `targetSdkVersion 30`. Moreover, not just `applicationContext`, but any other context (e.g. _Activity_) won't work either. I recommend to create an issue at the Google Issue Tracker.

Comment: Hi! Have you created the issue at the Google Issue Tracker yet?

Comment: I had exactly the same issue and here is my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/66460317/7237884

Comment: @Onik: I tried building with `compileSdkVersion 30` too, but still, the app crashes on my Samsung S10+ whenever a Toast is called (though it runs fine in the Android Studio device emulator)

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128403/toast-doesnt-work-on-real-device-after-adding-permissions

Answer (score 6):

### First method

Updating of `Android Emulator` to `30.4.5` version fixed bug for me. P.S. I also updated `Android SDK Platform-Tools` to `31.0.0` version (may be this helped too).

Menu `Tools` -> `SDK Manager` -> `SDK Tools`, set checkbox of `Android Emulator` to `V`-mode, press button `Apply`, press button `OK`, confirm.

P.S. Also after updating of those the Android Studio and emulators were closed and project was cleaned before new compilation.

### Second method

If you get this bug while using the last version of Android Emulator there is another solution. You can try the cold boot of emulator. Menu `Tools` -> `AVD Manager`. Find your emulator name, click button ▼ on the right side of it, select `Cold boot now` button.

Comment: check my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70300160/1069083